# What's wrong with my java code to rotate a jpeg photo?

Tags: java, image, jpeg

I simply want to enable the user of my web site to change the orientation of a submitted photo from horizontal to vertical. Here's my code:

```
public static final void rotatePhoto(String jpgFilename){
      BufferedImage originalImage = null, newImage=null;
      try{
         File file = new File(jpgFilename);
         originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
System.out.println("Photo.rotatePhoto(" +jpgFilename +") originalImage.getWidth(null)=" +originalImage.getWidth(null) +" originalImage.getHeight(null)=" +originalImage.getHeight(null)  );

         java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp opRotated = new java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp( java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1), null );
         newImage = opRotated.createCompatibleDestImage(originalImage, originalImage.getColorModel());
         opRotated.filter(originalImage, newImage);
      }catch (IOException e){
      }

      /// Write result to file::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      try{
         File outputfile = new File(testFilename);
         ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", outputfile);
      }catch(IOException ioE){
      }
   }
```

Problem is I get this error even though the System.out.println shows the width and height to be 640x480

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: Transformed width (0) is less than or equal to 0.
    java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.createCompatibleDestImage(AffineTransformOp.java:447)
    base.Photo.rotatePhoto(Photo.java:135)
    base.ProcessContent.handleInput(ProcessContent.java:245)
    servlets.ProcessServlet.doPost(ProcessServlet.java:74)
    servlets.ProcessServlet.doGet(ProcessServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new `AffineTransform` from scratch and using it in your `AffineTransformOp` constructor:

```
AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2, originalImage.getWidth() / 2, originalImage.getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
newImage = op.filter(originalImage, newImage);
```

You also have to make sure `newImage` contains the data returned by the `filter()` method.

Oddly enough, this will only work when you set the `formatName` in `ImageIO.write()` to "png". I tried using `jpg` and the result was a black picture.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had the same black result when i used Mohamed's code (above) but the change to png solved the problem. Really appreciated it!

Comment: I tried this and ended up with a square image when the original was landscape. The extra image area was black.

Answer (score 4):

By using: `AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1);`

Your AffineTransform is rotating by a positive number of quadrants by axis. That will mess up the Transform Operation since it depends on the x and y, whenever it creates the compatible image.

```
    int w = r.x + r.width;
    int h = r.y + r.height;
    if (w <= 0) {
        throw new RasterFormatException("Transformed width ("+w+
                                        ") is less than or equal to 0.");
    }
```

I would recommend doing it yourself:

```
public final void rotatePhoto(String jpgFilename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(jpgFilename);
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);

    // You could use Math.PI / 2, depends on your input.
    AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    affineTransform.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), originalImage.getWidth() / 2, originalImage.getHeight() / 2);

    // Now lets make that transform an operation, and we use it.
    AffineTransformOp opRotated = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);  
    BufferedImage newImage = opRotated.filter(originalImage, null);

    // Save the image.
    File outputfile = new File("rotated.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", outputfile);
}
```

UPDATE: Btw, it has been answered before on [How do I write a servlet which rotates images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289845/servlet-which-rotates-images-solved)

Comment: Mohamed:Thanks so much for your quick response. I used your exact code but changed the ImageIO.write param from jpg to png (as sugggested by 'KindOfAutomatic' in 2nd response) and it worked. thank you so much. I wasted all yesterday searching for the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Np! Yea  png is better quality! In StackOverflow, if the answer helped you, you usually check mark it as the accepted answer :)